# Package installation failing: Killed Warning message: In i.p(...) :

Tags: r, shiny-server, r-package

I am installing a package I have developed onto Shiny Server via devtools::install_github. It has always worked fine in the past.

Now, I am experiencing an issue I cannot figure out:

```
Installing package into ‘/srv/shiny-server/upei/renv/library/R-4.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘itembankr’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
Killed
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/RtmpWs2YM1/filed08029947685/itembankr_0.1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I install the package locally via devtools::install, it is fine with no problem.

What could be causing this?

I'm using renv to manage the project, if that's relevant.

Comment: The "Killed" line makes me think that the process was killed by a process supervisor (e.g. an out-of-memory killer). Is it possible that this machine is memory-constrained, or that installation of this package is taking a large amount of memory?

Comment: Thanks @KevinUshey, you were right; the package was too big. I .gitignored some large files and it now installs correctly.